# Missing number in this sequence?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

I heard this puzzle in a quiz I participated in:

> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 24, ?, 100, 121, 10000
>
> What is the missing number?

(You don't need to do any big calculations, and you don't need any advanced mathematical knowledge - just one basic concept that's known to many non-mathematical people.)

Comment: What happened to @d'alar'cop 's answer? It wasn't what I was looking for, but sounded like it could be an interesting alternative!

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584592/weird-sequence-of-numbers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths and has an exact duplicate in that site

Comment: @skv - It's still a puzzle, even if it's a maths puzzle. Didn't know about the duplicate though.

Comment: @randal'thor I agree, I am guilty of posting pure math questions here earlier too, but unless its disguised in words, its tough to justify that they are more than calculations, and hence should be discouraged on this site, I am sure you will understand

Comment: hi rand, I deleted my answer because I couldn't really make a base-8 pattern work nicely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> According the google the answer be 31. 
>  
>  The sequence is 16 in base 16-n.

Comment: Are these two separate attempts, or one answer with reasoning? I can't see how triangular numbers give 31.

Comment: Separate attempts, I'll post up my reasoning for the first answer, just wanted to get in first.

Comment: Don't think is related to triangular numbers, because 16 and 17, for example, aren't.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008713

Comment: @Geobits: using OEIS is cheating! :-(

Comment: I gave the link because it has an explanation, not as the answer. You already have that.

Comment: @Mew - I want to know how you got this so quickly! Did you work it out or just look it up on OEIS? (+1, and I'll accept unless someone else gives a really amazing alternative answer.)

Comment: @randal'thor, using my intelligence.

Comment: @Mew Sorry, didn't mean to be rude!

Comment: "just one basic concept that's known to many non-mathematical people" .. oof, I wonder how many people who aren't that into maths know about bases and especially its conversions

Comment: @No.7892142 - I was thinking of the computer people that StackExchange seems to be full of. If you know binary and base 10, then at least you're familiar with the concept of different bases.

Comment: @Mew - Google is almost as cheating as OEIS! (unless you were joking)

Comment: @randal'thor Computer people are also mathematical people, though. Granted, we are on SE, but it does require _some_ mathematical knowledge.