# Just another sequence

Tags: number-sequence

*Hey guys, I've been into brainteasers since I was little and recently decided to make a puzzle-related website. I figured that this will be the best place to share some of my problems and see if they are any fun. I guess they are too easy, but hope that will entertain you for a bit.*

> **Just another sequence**
>
> 1, 3, 7, 12, 18, 26, 35, 45, 56, ?

*P.S. Please, let me know if you have seen identical puzzle elsewhere, don't want to take someone's credit, even accidentally.*

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HofstadterFigure-FigureSequence.html

Comment: @qwertylpc Aha! That's the same pattern as I found, only perhaps a more elegant way of expressing it.

Comment: Thank you guys. As a mathematician, I feel a little bit embarrassed... Should have expected it to be well-known already.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan I had a similar experience with [my very first question here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/missing-number-in-this-sequence) :-)

Comment: Yeah, I feel there are not many more fun sequences to be discovered:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define the sequence inductively as follows.

- The first term is $1$.
- For all $n$, the $(n+1)$th term of the sequence is the sum of the $n$th term and the smallest number which hasn't appeared among the first $n$ terms and the first $n-1$ differences between consecutive terms.

Or in table form:

real terms: $1,3,7,12,18,26,35,45,56,69,\dots$
differences: $2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,14,\dots$